# Checking for Null Pointer not working in C (Giving SegFault Error)

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

So I'm checking for NULL pointer/Empty string and returning 0 if either are found. However, I seem to be getting a `Segmentation Fault` error in one of the compilers. If someone could help me figure out what could possibly be causing it. Apparently when `empty strings` and `null pointers` are used as input the error comes up. However, this error is not coming up in the compiler that I am using, but is coming up in another compiler (one that I am being graded on).

`rpsls.c`

```
#include <string.h>

int rpsls(const char *player1, const char *player2)
{

    if (*player1 == '\0' || *player2 == '\0' || player1 == NULL || player2 == NULL || strcmp(player1, player2) == 0)
        return 0;

    char *r = "rock";
    char *p = "paper";
    char *si = "scissors";
    char *l = "lizard";
    char *s = "Spock";



    if (!strcmp(player1, r) && !strcmp(player2, si))
        return 1;
    else if (!strcmp(player1, p) && !strcmp(player2, r))
        return 1;
    else if (!strcmp(player1, si) && !strcmp(player2, p))
        return 1;
    else if (!strcmp(player1, l) && !strcmp(player2, s))
        return 1;
    else if (!strcmp(player1, s) && !strcmp(player2, si))
        return 1;
    else if (!strcmp(player1, r) && !strcmp(player2, l))
        return 1;
    else if (!strcmp(player1, p) && !strcmp(player2, s))
        return 1;
    else if (!strcmp(player1, si) && !strcmp(player2, l))
        return 1;
    else if (!strcmp(player1, l) && !strcmp(player2, p))
        return 1;
    else if (!strcmp(player1, s) && !strcmp(player2, r))
        return 1;

    if (!strcmp(player2, r) && !strcmp(player1, si))
        return -1;
    else if (!strcmp(player2, p) && !strcmp(player1, r))
        return -1;
    else if (!strcmp(player2, si) && !strcmp(player1, p))
        return -1;
    else if (!strcmp(player2, l) && !strcmp(player1, s))
        return -1;
    else if (!strcmp(player2, s) && !strcmp(player1, si))
        return -1;
    else if (!strcmp(player2, r) && !strcmp(player1, l))
        return -1;
    else if (!strcmp(player2, p) && !strcmp(player1, s))
        return -1;
    else if (!strcmp(player2, si) && !strcmp(player1, l))
        return -1;
    else if (!strcmp(player2, l) && !strcmp(player1, p))
        return -1;
    else if (!strcmp(player2, s) && !strcmp(player1, r))
        return -1;

    return 0;

}
```

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rpsls(const char *player1, const char *player2);

int main (void)
{
  printf ("%d\n", rpsls("rock","paper"));
  printf ("%d\n", rpsls("rock","rock"));
  printf ("%d\n", rpsls("paper","rock"));
  printf ("%d\n", rpsls("lizard",(char*)0));
  printf ("%d\n", rpsls("",(char*)0));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expressions are evaluated left to right with the logical OR operator so in

```
if (*player1 == '\0' || *player2 == '\0' ||
    player1 == NULL || player2 == NULL ||
    strcmp(player1, player2) == 0)
```

you dereference `NULL` in `*player1 == '\0'` before testing `player1 == NULL`.

`*player1==NULL` is equivalent to `player1[0]==NULL`.  If `player1` points to memory you didn't allocate, the effects of trying to read this memory are undefined.  Anything can happen at this point.  In your local tests, you report that this appears to work (I'm sceptical about this); in your teacher's tests, your program doesn't have permission to read address `0` and segfaults.

You need to reorder the expressions

```
if (player1 == NULL || *player1 == '\0' ||
    player2 == NULL || *player2 == '\0' ||
    strcmp(player1, player2) == 0)
```

Comment: also interesting what behaviour the other compiler (the one thats not throwing a segfault) is exhibiting. (and what compiler is it?)

Comment: I'm fairly new to pointers, could you please explain what you mean by "deference" exactly? The first one checks if the string is empty, checking if the string is empty before checking if the pointer is null makes the latter check useless? If a string is empty, the pointer doesn't exactly need to be NULL correct? Why do we need to check if pointer is NULL before checking if the string that it points to is empty?

Comment: @amdixon I am using CodeBlocks

Comment: @Maaz I've updated my answer with more detail on what dereferencing NULL means and why it is bad.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (*player1 == '\0' || *player2 == '\0' || player1 == NULL || player2 == NULL || strcmp(player1, player2) == 0)
        return 0;
```

You're dereferencing the pointers before checking for NULL.  Kind of defeats the purpose of the NULL check.

Check for NULL first, then dereference.